# What must be included if you want to get individualized help?

Tags: discussion

As our site ages, questions are necessarily going to focus on very individual suggestions, as the broad general questions will tend to be duplicates.

What should be included in an individualized question if you want it to get a good answer here?

Comment: Thanks for starting this. This will really be helpful to reference for newcomers and improving questions.

Answer (score 2):

- Your goal, and be as specific as possible
- Age, gender, bodyfat %
- Goal-relevant performance numbers

  - If your goal is strength, what do you squat, press, deadlift, etc.
  - If your goal is speed, what is your 100m, 10km time, whatever you do
  - If your goal is a body composition (toning), what is your bodyfat %
  - etc.
- How those performance numbers have changed over time
- What is your current program? Be as specific as possible. What lifts? How much weight? How many reps, sets? How are they scheduled within a week? What is your run schedule like? Etc.
- What is your diet, exactly? A food log for a typical day or week is helpful.
- Why are you not happy with the progress you're making?

Despite all this detail, your question should still be focused on a particular aspect of your training (https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/415/4644). Identifying a specific goal, and why you believe you're failing to meet that goal is an important limit of scope. If you fail to do that, the question becomes overly broad and may be closed.

Comment: It may be informative to use [my recent highly-specific question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14391/how-do-i-track-improvement-in-my-box-jump) as a test case: I omitted age, bodyfat %, goal-relevant powerlifting numbers, diet, and past performance. I'm going to edit my question now!